# SQL Server: the ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, database-cursor

I have a trigger that works (it fires when it has to) but I still get an error.
I understand the error but I don't know how to resolve it.

I tried to put some BEGIN TRANSACTION with all the code who go with it but I think my grammar is wrong because I always get a timeout!

So my question is, where exactly do I have to put my `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statements in my code?

Also, do I need 3 `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statements since I have 3 `ROLLBACK`?

Thank you in advance!

My code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_CheckOverlap]
ON [dbo].[Tranche]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @IdVol INT, @IdTranche INT, 
            @AgeMinInserted DATE, @AgeMaxInserted DATE

    SELECT @AgeMinInserted = t.TRA_Age_Min 
    FROM Tranche t
    JOIN inserted AS i ON t.TRA_Id = i.TRA_Id

    SELECT @AgeMaxInserted = t.TRA_Age_Max 
    FROM Tranche t
    JOIN inserted AS i ON t.TRA_Id = i.TRA_Id

    DECLARE CR_TrancheVol CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT t.TRA_Vol_Id,t.TRA_Id
        FROM Tranche t
        JOIN inserted AS i ON t.TRA_Vol_Id = i.TRA_Vol_Id;

    OPEN CR_TrancheVol

    FETCH CR_TrancheVol INTO @IdVol, @IdTranche

    WHILE( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @AgeMin DATE, @AgeMax DATE

        SELECT @AgeMin = t.TRA_Age_Min 
        FROM Tranche t
        WHERE t.TRA_Id = @IdTranche

        SELECT @AgeMax = t.TRA_Age_Max 
        FROM Tranche t
        WHERE t.TRA_Id = @IdTranche

        IF @AgeMinInserted > @AgeMin AND @AgeMinInserted < @AgeMax
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Trans1'
            RAISERROR('Overlap: Date de naissance minimum déjà couverte', 1, 420)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

        IF @AgeMaxInserted > @AgeMin AND @AgeMaxInserted < @AgeMax
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Trans2'
            RAISERROR('Overlap: Date de naissance maximum déjà couverte', 1, 421)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

        IF @AgeMinInserted < @AgeMin AND @AgeMaxInserted > @AgeMax
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Trans3'
            RAISERROR('Overlap: Tranche déjà couverte complètement', 1, 422)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

        FETCH CR_TrancheVol INTO @IdVol, @IdTranche
    END

    CLOSE CR_TrancheVol
    DEALLOCATE CR_TrancheVol
END
```

**EDIT**:

Okay, so I tried your answer without cursor (I understand that my way was clearly not the best!) but for now it doesn't work.

My goal: I have a DB to book a flight. In this DB, i have a table "Tranche" who contains some dates and some prices (depending when the flight is).

I need to prevent and avoid any overlap of birthdate, for example:

```
1y-17y: 80€
18y-64y: 120€
```

So my trigger has to fire when I try to insert 17y-63y: xx € (because I already have a price for those ages).

Sorry if my English is not perfect btw!

Here's my table "Tranche":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuQH8.png

TRA_Vol_ID is a foreign key of another table "Vol" who contain the flights

Here's the code I have atm:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_CheckOverlap]
ON [dbo].[Tranche]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    /*
    Some SQL goes here to get the value of Minimum age.
    I assuming that it doesn't vary by entry, however,
    I don't really have enough information to go on to tell
    */
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @MinAge DATE, @MaxAge DATE

    SELECT @MinAge = t.TRA_Age_Min 
    FROM Tranche t
    JOIN Vol AS v ON v.VOL_Id = t.TRA_Vol_Id
    JOIN inserted AS i ON t.TRA_Id = i.TRA_Id
    WHERE t.TRA_Id = i.TRA_Id

    SELECT @MaxAge = t.TRA_Age_Max
    FROM Tranche t
    JOIN inserted AS i ON t.TRA_Id = i.TRA_Id
    JOIN Vol AS v ON v.VOL_Id = t.TRA_Vol_Id
    WHERE t.TRA_Id = i.TRA_Id

    IF (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN i.TRA_Age_Min > @MinAge AND i.TRA_Age_Min < @MaxAge  THEN 1 END) FROM inserted i) > 0 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Overlap: Birthday min reached',1,430);
        ROLLBACK
    END
    ELSE IF (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN i.TRA_Age_Max > @MinAge AND i.TRA_Age_Max < @MaxAge  THEN 1 END) FROM inserted i) > 0 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Overlap: Birthday max reached',1,430);
        ROLLBACK
    END
END
```

Comment: Wanna share the error?

Comment: @dfundako the title...

Comment: OP you are trying to encapsulate the logic of the 3 IF statements into a single transaction, correct?

Comment: Why is this a `CURSOR`..? Blargh. An `INSERT` with a few 1,000 rows is going to perform terribly.

Comment: In fact, this trigger is assuming that someone is inserting one row at a time only. There's a lot wrong with this. If someone inserts more than 1 row, it's not going to perform as you intend. What is your real goal here?

Comment: @JacobH --> I dont know if in this case i have to encapsulate the 3 if statements into a single transaction, or if i can have 3 transactions? (im still learning as you can see lol)

Comment: @Larnu --> This table can only be edited in sqlserver with sa account.
I try to avoid the overlap of TRA_Age_Min & TRA_Age_Max

Comment: Just because only a sysadmin can `INSERT` into the table doesn't mean they can only `INSERT` one row at a time. A sysadmin can pretty much do whatever they want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what the OP's goals are here. However, I wanted to post a small example how to do a dataset approach, and how to check all the rows in one go.

At the moment, the trigger the OP has will only "work" if the user is inserting 1 row. Any more, and things aren't going to work properly. Then we also have the problem of the `CURSOR`. I note that the declaration of the cursors aren't referencing `inserted` at all, so I don't actually know what their goals are. It seems more like the OP is auditing the data already in the table when a `INSERT` occurs, not the data that is being inserted. This seems very odd.

Anyway, this isn't a solution for the OP, however, I don't have enough room in a comment to put all this. Maybe it'll push the OP in the right direction.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_CheckOverlap]
ON [dbo].[Tranche]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    /*
    Some SQL goes here to get the value of Minimum age.
    I assuming that it doesn't vary by entry, however,
    I don't really have enough information to go on to tell
    */

    IF (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN i.Age < @MinAge THEN 1 END) FROM inserted i) > 0 BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Age too low',1,430);
        ROLLBACK
    END
    ELSE
    IF (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN i.Age > @MaxAge THEN 1 END) FROM inserted i) > 0 BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Age too high',1,430);
        ROLLBACK
    END


END
```

The question at hand seems to very much be an xy question; the problem isn't the `CURSOR` or the `ROLLBACK`, the problems with this trigger are much more fundamental. I'd suggest revising your question and actually explaining your goal of what you want to do with your Trigger. Provide DDL to `CREATE` your table and `INSERT` statements for any sample data. You might want to also provide some `INSERT` statements that will have different results for your trigger (make sure to include ones that have more than one row to be inserted at a time).

I realise this is more commenting, however, again, there is definitely not enough room in a comment for me to write all this. :)

Comment: I've edit my initial post with some additionals informations :-)

Comment: I think i found it! Have to try this tonight (just have to change every < >)

Comment: Hello, its not working =/ Could you please help me? My trigger dont fire at all atm.. :(

Comment: @Korpin the one you have in your post is only `AFTER INSERT`. Do you have an `AFTER UPDATE` as well?

Comment: Nope, this is the only one trigger i do have! It need to avoid any overlap like an Instead of Trigger actually

Comment: Hello, im still stuck =/ Should i create a new subject? I don't know if it is possible to up my post..